# How to fix becoming root using (delegate_to)?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to become root user for one of my tasks. However, when I see the `delegate_to` field for the task and enter the correct root password, it keeps giving me the fatal error `Incorrect su password`.

I have already tried messing around with the `delegate_facts: true`. However, I had no luck with getting it to work.

**Code:**

```
- hosts: 10.x.x.1
- tasks:


- name: Set root password for host
  set_fact:
     ansible_become_password: "{{ tempPassword }}"

- name: whoami as root (su)
  command: whoami
  register: output_root_su
  delegate_to: "{{ delegate_host }}"
  become_user: root
  become_method: su
  become: yes
```

The desired result should give an output of "root". Instead this is the output I get:
`fatal: [10.x.x.2]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Incorrect su password"}`

Answer (score 2):

(Tested with ansible 2.7.9)

*set_fact* should not work. If *ansible_become_password* is declared by *set_fact*

```
  set_fact:
     ansible_become_password: "{{ tempPassword }}"
```

the play should fail with

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "Timeout (12s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt: "}
```

Declare *ansible_become_password* either in the **vars** section of the play

```
- hosts: 10.x.x.1
  vars:
    ansible_become_password: "{{ tempPassword }}"
  tasks:
```

, or in the task

```
- hosts: 10.x.x.1
  tasks:
    - command: whoami
      register: result
      delegate_to: "{{ delegate_host }}"
      become: yes
      become_user: root
      become_method: su
      vars:
        ansible_become_password: "{{ tempPassword }}"
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout
```

Quoting from [Connecting to hosts: behavioral inventory parameters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#connecting-to-hosts-behavioral-inventory-parameters)

> **ansible_become_password**
>   Equivalent to ansible_sudo_password or ansible_su_password, allows you to set the privilege escalation password (**never store this variable in plain text; always use a vault**. See Variables and Vaults)

Comment: It works still, however, I wanted to use the password like 4 times through out the playbook. When I add ```become: yes``` to the task it wont work. Only for the very first play I run.